# How can i get refreshtoken from headers when i use node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, jwt

I have two accesstoken and refreshtoken in authorization.

The one in front is the accesstoken and the one in the back is the refreshtoken. Getting the accesstoken in front was successful, how can I filter out the refreshtoken?

this is headers

```
headers: {
                authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjE3MjA2OTc4MzciLCJpYXQiOjE2MjA0NTkzMTYsImV4cCI6MTYyMDQ1OTMyMX0.eYTj0L2g6Z1BM7C-EmtJUXWw9l_t5ua59-w5ZQrvTfU    
  
   //this is refreshtoken  //          eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjE3MjA2OTc4MzciLCJpYXQiOjE2MjA0NTkzMTYsImV4cCI6MTYyMDQ1OTQzNn0.8rl3avx3eL7DhxCgu1kUTqYr_f2fjNs7o-ZxEUTsKs8',
}
```

Getting the accesstoken in front was successful, like this

```
        const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
        const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
        console.log("token::::::::", token);  
        //success get accesstoken
```

then how can i get refreshtoken?

i want to get refreshtoken like this

```
console.log(refreshtoken)
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjE3MjA2OTc4MzciLCJpYXQiOjE2MjA0NTkzMTYsImV4cCI6MTYyMDQ1OTQzNn0.8rl3avx3eL7DhxCgu1kUTqYr_f2fjNs7o-ZxEUTsKs8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your headers write,

```
headers: {
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjE3MjA2OTc4MzciLCJpYXQiOjE2MjA0NTkzMTYsImV4cCI6MTYyMDQ1OTMyMX0.eYTj0L2g6Z1BM7C-EmtJUXWw9l_t5ua59-w5ZQrvTfU    
  refreshToken : "Your Refresh Token here..."
}
```

Then in your server side,

```
const refreshToken = req.headers["refreshToken"];
console.log(refreshToken) // This will be the token
```